# Setting variables in sql script with Java

Tags: java, mysql

Is there a way or library to fix a variable in a SQL file? Im trying to write a method called setvariable to replace ${schema} in my SQL script.

For example

```
public class App 
{

    public static void runscripts(Connection conn) throws SQLException{
        try {
            ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conn);
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/sampleScript.sql"));
            sr.runScript(reader);   
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            conn.close();
        }


    }
    public static void setvariable(){
        // SET ${schema} to PUBLIC
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {   
        Properties prop = new Properties ();
        prop.put("user", "bbb");
        prop.put("password", "xxx#");
        prop.put("db", "SIMPLE_DEMO");

        String url = "xxxx://aaaa.";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);
        setvariable();
        runscripts(conn);
    }
}
```

my SQL script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ${schema}.cricketers_data(
   First_Name VARCHAR(255),
   Last_Name VARCHAR(255),
   Date_Of_Birth date,
   Place_Of_Birth VARCHAR(255),
   Country VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO cricketers_data values('Shikhar', 'Dhawan', DATE('1981-12-05'), 'Delhi', 'India');
```

Comment: do you need only for `schema` or any replacement? because I think there is a `yourConnection.setSchema("schema");`

Comment: Yes im aware of that. But i plan to use dynamic schemas as there are multiple SQL files and each file may have different schemas/tables. ALso some maybe inert into table ${user_id}